# Efficiency of floating point division and checking values beforehand if eq

Tags: java, math, optimization, floating-point, division

I have a situation where I *might* need to apply a multiplier to a value in order to get the correct results.  This involves computing the value using floating point division.

I'm thinking it would be a good idea to check the values before I perform floating point logic on them to save processor time, however I'm not sure how efficient it will be at run-time either way.

I'm assuming that the `if` check is 1 or 2 instructions (been a while since assembly class), and that the floating point operation is going to be many more than that.

```
//Check 
if (a != 10) {              //1 or 2 instructions?
    b *= (float) a / 10;    //Many instructions?
}
```

Value `a` is going to be '10' most of the time, however there are a few instances where it wont be.  Is the floating point division going to take very many cycles even if `a` is equal to the divisor?

Will the previous code with the `if` statement execute more efficiently than simply the next one without?

```
//Don't check
b *= (float) a / 10;    //Many instructions?
```

Granted there wont be any noticable difference either way, however I'm curious as to the behavior of the floating point multiplication when the divisor is equal to the dividend in case things get processor heavy.

Comment: Have you tried microbenchmarking both versions?

Comment: No, not yet, I will update my question when I do

Comment: Yeah, benchmark first, in order to determine if it matters; if not, do the simplest thing.  That said: a branch miss should be more expensive than a division, so a check shouldn't be worthwhile unless the branch is highly predictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is in some incredibly tight loop, executed billions of times, so the difference of 1-2 instructions matters, since otherwise you should probably not bother --

Yes you are right to weigh the cost of the additional check each time, versus the savings when the check is true. But my guess is that it has to be true a lot to overcome not only the extra overhead, but the fact that you're introducing a branch, which will ultimately do more to slow you down via a pipeline stall in the CPU in the JIT-compiled code than you'll gain otherwise.

If `a == 10` a whole lot, I'd imagine there's a better and faster way to take advantage of that somehow, earlier in the code.

Comment: +1 For re-factoring out the check into a less trafficked area of code

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, floating-point multiplication is much less expensive than division, so this might be faster than both:

```
b *= (a * 0.1);
```

Comment: If you can live with the fact that this is NOT exactly the same as division by 10..

Answer (score 1):

If you do end up needing to optimize this code I would recommend using Caliper to do micro benchmarks of your inner loops. It's very hard to predict accurately what sort of effect these small modifications will have.  Especially in Java where how the VM behaves is bit of an unknown since in theory it can optimize the code on the fly.  Best to try several strategies and see what works.

http://code.google.com/p/caliper/